# How to make javascript function to fire consistently

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a HTML page with a simple form that calculates the product of two input fields and displays the result in a div . It calls a on click javascript funciton.
However , after I have submitted the first time , the form doesn't work from second time onwards , the page keeps refreshing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <style>
    #header {
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
        margin : -8px -8px 0;
        background-color: lightgrey;
     }
                 
                 #controls{
                     
                   margin-left: 475px;  
                   
                     
                 }
                 
                 #weight{
                     
                    margin-bottom:25px;
                 }
                 
                 #cost{
                     margin-bottom:25px;
                 }
                 
                 #compute{
                     
                     margin-bottom:25px;
                     margin-left: 300x
                 }
             
             #result{
                 
                   margin-left: 50px
             }
  </style>
</head>
    
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr style="width:100%">
                <td style="width:20%">
                    <span>
                        <img align="left" src="logo.jpeg" width="120px" height="120px">
                    </span>
                </td>    
                <td style="width: 60%;">
                    <span>
                        <center>
                            <h1>DATAX Shipping Company</h1>
                        </center>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%; padding-bottom: 7%;padding-left:5%;">
                    <span>
                        <a href="#" id="signup">Sign up</a>
                        <a href="#" id="login" style="padding-left:30px">Log in</a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <form id="controls">
      <div class="title">
          <h3>Calculation of Shipping charge</h3>   
      </div>
            
       <div><label> Total Product Weight <input id="weight"/></label></div>
       <div><label>Shipping cost (Per Kg) <input id="cost"/></label></div>
         <button id="compute" onclick="return result()"/>Compute</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
</form>
       

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var weight;
    var cost;
    var result;
    function result(){
        
        weight=document.getElementById("weight").value;
        cost=document.getElementById("cost").value;
        console.log(weight);
        console.log(cost);
        result=weight*cost;
        console.log(result);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="The Total Shipment charge is "+result;
        return false;
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm testing with below scenarios

weight = 4 , distance =5
Weight = 10 , distance = 15

From second iteration onwards it seems to fail

Comment: first off you do not need the `return` in your `onclick` html attribute.

Comment: @ThomasValadez — Without that, the submit button will submit the form.

Comment: good point, don't put it in a `form` or use `e.preventDefault();`. Also I would kill the `return false` at the end of the function. That is just how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I made the change and it worked. But, I still don't understand how i'm overwriting the variable result. Would you mind throwing some light on that. Is the value of the var result conflicting with getElementById("result") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```js
document.getElementById("compute").addEventListener('click', result);
function result(e) {
    // Since its a form, you need to use preventDefault()
    e.preventDefault();
    // Define input variables
    var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var cost   = document.getElementById("cost").value;
    // Result variable
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    // Check if the value is a number
    if( isNaN(weight) || isNaN(cost) ) {
        result.innerHTML = "Please enter a Valid Number!";
    }
    // Final result
    else {
        result.innerHTML = "The Total Shipment charge is " + (weight * cost);
    }
}

document.getElementById("resetForm").addEventListener('click', resultReset);
function resultReset(e) {
    // prevent submit
    e.preventDefault();
    // Reset form
    document.getElementById("controls").reset();
}
```

```css
#header {
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 margin : -8px -8px 0;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

#controls{
 margin-left: 475px;
}

#weight{
 margin-bottom:25px;
}

#cost{
 margin-bottom:25px;
}

#compute{
 margin-bottom:25px;
 margin-left: 300x
}

#result{
 margin-left: 50px
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr style="width:100%">
      <td style="width:20%">
        <span>
          <img align="left" src="logo.jpeg" width="120px" height="120px">
        </span>
      </td>    
      <td style="width: 60%;">
        <span>
          <center>
            <h1>DATAX Shipping Company</h1>
          </center>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 40%; padding-bottom: 7%;padding-left:5%;">
        <span>
          <a href="#" id="signup">Sign up</a>
          <a href="#" id="login" style="padding-left:30px">Log in</a>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<form id="controls">
    <div class="title">
        <h3>Calculation of Shipping charge</h3>   
    </div>
    <div><label> Total Product Weight <input id="weight"/></label></div>
    <div><label>Shipping cost (Per Kg) <input id="cost"/></label></div>
    <button id="compute">Compute</button>
    <button id="resetForm">Reset</button>
    <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the variable `result` inside the function, you need to change it to something else:

```js
 var weight;
        var cost;
        var result;
        function result(){
            
            weight=document.getElementById("weight").value;
            cost=document.getElementById("cost").value;
            console.log(weight);
            console.log(cost);
            xresult=weight*cost;
            console.log(xresult);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="The Total Shipment charge is "+xresult;
            return false;
        }
```

```css
#header {
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
        margin : -8px -8px 0;
        background-color: lightgrey;
     }
                 
                 #controls{
                     
                   margin-left: 475px;  
                   
                     
                 }
                 
                 #weight{
                     
                    margin-bottom:25px;
                 }
                 
                 #cost{
                     margin-bottom:25px;
                 }
                 
                 #compute{
                     
                     margin-bottom:25px;
                     margin-left: 300x
                 }
             
             #result{
                 
                   margin-left: 50px
             }
```

```html
<div id="header">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr style="width:100%">
                <td style="width:20%">
                    <span>
                        <img align="left" src="logo.jpeg" width="120px" height="120px">
                    </span>
                </td>    
                <td style="width: 60%;">
                    <span>
                        <center>
                            <h1>DATAX Shipping Company</h1>
                        </center>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%; padding-bottom: 7%;padding-left:5%;">
                    <span>
                        <a href="#" id="signup">Sign up</a>
                        <a href="#" id="login" style="padding-left:30px">Log in</a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <form id="controls">
      <div class="title">
          <h3>Calculation of Shipping charge</h3>   
      </div>
            
       <div><label> Total Product Weight <input id="weight"/></label></div>
       <div><label>Shipping cost (Per Kg) <input id="cost"/></label></div>
         <button id="compute" onclick="return result()"/>Compute</button>
        <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could the user declare `var result` inside the function to avoid overwriting `result` in the global namespace, while keeping their desired variable name?

Comment: Yes, but it would be helluva confusing bit of code :)

Comment: Fair. Probably a reason to change the function name to something like `getCharge`.

Comment: Yep, probably just easier to type `result` though

Comment: Thanks for your reasponse , appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

That because you using the same name (result) as a variable and again as a function name as the same scope. you need to change on of them. you can change the function name to (getResult).